# Proof of source coding theorem using asymptotic equipartition property(AEP)

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy, ergodic-theory

In [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem) wikipedia article, there is a proof given for one of the directions of the Shannon's *source coding theorem* using the *asymptotic equipartition property* (AEP). I am unable to follow the proof. Here are the relevant definitions. To get the idea of the proof I wish to see the implication only for a special case (of the direction of interest) of the source coding theorem, which is what I state below.

For a finite set $\Sigma$, we write $\Sigma^*$ to mean the set of all the finite strings than can be formed using the elements of $\Sigma$.

A **binary code** is a function $c:S\to \{0, 1\}^*$. The extension of $c$ is the function $c^*:S^*\to \{0, 1\}^*$ which is defined as $c(s_1\cdots s_n)=c(s_1)\cdots c(s_n)$, the concatenation of the strings $c(s_i)$'s.
A binary code is said to be **uniquely decodable** if its extension is injective. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_code#Uniquely_decodable_codes) for more context.

Define the **length map** $\ell:\{0, 1\}^*\to \mathbb N$ which maps a binary string to its length.

> **Source Coding Theorem.** Let $S$ be a finite set and $\mu$ be a probability measure on $S$ and $c:S\to \{0, 1\}^*$ be a uniquely decodable code. Then $\mathbb E[\ell(c)] = \int_S \ell\circ c\ d\mu\geq H_\mu = -\sum_{s\in S}\mu(s)\log_2\mu(s)$.

For each $n\geq 1$ and $\epsilon>0$, equip $S^n$ with the product measure $\mu^n$ and define the set
$$A_n^{\epsilon} = \{(s_1, \ldots, s_n)\in S^n:\ \left|-\frac{1}{n}\mu^n(s_1, \ldots, s_n) - H_\mu\right|< \epsilon\}$$

Assume that the following is true (a consequence of AEP)

> **Consequence of AEP.** For each $\epsilon>0$, there is $n$ large enough so that $\mu^n(A_n^\epsilon)>1-\epsilon$.

Now the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%27s_source_coding_theorem) hints (last line of the section *Proof:Source Coding Theorem*) that the source coding theorem follows from the fact that "any set of size smaller than $A_n^\epsilon$ (in the sense of exponent) would cover a set of probability bounded away from 1."

I do not even follow what this means and am unable to see how the coding enters the picture here. Can somebody please elaborate on the hint or provide a reference where more details can be found?

Comment: that's not the source coding theorem Wikipedia is talking about

Comment: @mathworker21 Wikipedia has two headings: *Source coding theorem* and *Source coding theorem for symbol Codes.* The statement for the former is made informally. I was assuming that the latter (what I am really after) is a special case of the former. Is that not right?

Comment: it may be, but my point was you didn't mention the converse in your question, but you're asking about the proof of the converse

Comment: @mathworker21 I had mentioned that I was interested in 'one of the directions' and that is the direction I have stated.

Comment: yes, sorry, I just had a brain fart. I knew you had it right when writing my answer

Comment: Okay. Thanks. Let me try to understand your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's going on in the proof Wikipedia gave of "achievability". A very small set contains nearly all of the strings that will be generated, probability-wise. I.e., the typical set has an exponentially small proportion of tuples $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ but has $1-o(1)$ of the probability. Since the typical set is so small, you don't need too many bits to describe the typical set; if a set has $k$ elements, you only need $\log_2(k)$ bits.

And the converse is true. If you want to describe a set of $k$ tuples, you need at least $\log_2(k)$ bits. So if you can compress into fewer than $H_\mu$ bits with probability close to $1$, there is a set of tuples of size less than $2^{H_\mu}$ with probability close to $1$, but there just isn't.

Comment: For the converse, can you say where have you used the unique decodability? (Without unique decodability the statement is false since if $S=\{a, b, c, d\}$, $\mu$ is uniform, and $c:S\to \{0, 1\}^*$ is defined as $c(a)=0, c(b)=1, c(c)=00, c(d)=01$, then $\mathbb E[\ell\circ c]=3/2$ while $H_\mu=2$.)

Comment: @caffeinemachine saying if a set has size less than $2^{H_\mu}$, it has probability bounded away from $1$. if there's not unique decodability, you can fit much more stuff into a small set. unique decodability gives injectivity, so sizes are preserved

Comment: So I guess your argument is that, writing $L=\ell\circ c$, suppose $\mathbb E[L]=H_\mu-\epsilon$. Then taking $n$ independent samples $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ from $S$ we see that $L(X_1)+\cdots L(X_n)\leq n((H_\mu)-\epsilon)$ happens with high probability. So the set of points $B_n=\{x\in S^n:\ L(x)\leq n(H_\mu-\epsilon)\}$ has size exponentially small compared to $|S^n|$ but it's probability approaches $1$ as $n\to \infty$, And this cannot happen. Am I right?

Comment: @caffeinemachine yup! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I am struggling with the 'and this cannot happen' part in my last comment. I have articulated that part as a separate thread here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3645195/

Comment: @caffeinemachine it just follows from AEP (converse of the consequence of AEP you gave). See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3348953/limit-of-an-infimum-defined-by-probabilites/3353727#3353727)