# Small in uniform measure cannot be too big in another measure.

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $S$ be a finite set and $\nu$ be a probability measure on $S$ with full support (that is, $\mu(s)>0$ for all $s\in S$). Let $\mu$ be the uniform probability measure on $S$. Endow each $S^n$ with the product measures $\mu^n$ and $\nu^n$. 
Suppose that for each $n\geq 1$ there is a subset $B_n$ of $S^n$ such that

1) $\displaystyle \mu^n(B_n)\leq \frac{1}{2^n}$.
2) $\lim_{n\to \infty} \nu^n(B_n)\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$.

(1) says that $B_n$ is exponentially smaller in size compared to $S^n$ and (2) says that $B_n$ is big according to $\nu^n$.

> **Problem.** I am trying to show that the above cannot happen.

**Attempt.** Let $|S|=k$. Choose integers $p, q>1$ such that such that $1/p+1/q=1$.
Let $F_n:S^n\to \mathbb R$ be defined as $F_n(x)= k^n\nu^n(x)$. Thus $F_n$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative $d\nu^n/d\mu^n$. 
Now
$$\nu^n(B_n) = \int_{S^n} \chi_{B_n}F_n\ d\mu^n\leq \|\chi_{B_n}\|_{p}\|F_n\|_q$$
where we have used Holder's inequality (the norms are with respect to $\mu^n$).
Noting that $\sum_{x\in S^n}\nu^n(x)^q=(\sum_{x\in S}\nu(x)^q)^n$, we get that
$$\|F_n\|_q = \left[k^{1/p}\left(\sum_{x\in S} \nu(x)^q\right)^{1/q}\right]^{n}$$
and
$$\|\chi_{B_n}\|_p \leq \frac{1}{2^{n/p}}$$
So when $k=2$ we get the desired result (for which we could argue directly) by choosing $p=q=2$.
We don't seem to get anything for $k>2$. If one could choose $p$ and $q$ such that $(k/2)^{1/p}\|\nu\|_q<1$ then we are done but this is artificial.

Comment: see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3348953/limit-of-an-infimum-defined-by-probabilites/3353727#3353727)

Comment: Thanks. I'll study your answer. But there must be a simple proof of it too. I think.

Comment: by the way, I don't know if what you want to prove in this question is true. The "typical set" discussed in your other question is exponentially small but has nearly all the probability (I say this in the answer I linked to). The base of the exponent is what is important..

Comment: I see. I was also getting convinced that this might be false. I guess one may be able to  construct a counterexample using random methods.

Comment: I mean, just have $\nu$ have small entropy and take $B_n$ to be the typical set

Comment: I haven't digested AEP and related ideas yet. My recent posts a directed towards understanding it. Thanks for your insights.

Comment: are u good on this question now?

Comment: Yes. I am. I think I now have a feel for AEP. For Bernoulli shifts it is like the Law of Large Numbers.

Comment: i think it is always like law of large numbers

Comment: How do you see the similarity for an ergodic transformation $T:X\to X$?

Comment: maybe we mean different things by aep. i just meant what was proven in the answer i linked above

Comment: I meant the following: Let $\mu$ be a probability measure on $X$ and $T:X\to X$ be ergodic. Let $\alpha$ be a finite partition of $X$ with $H(\alpha)<\infty$. Fix $\varepsilon >0$. Then there is $n_0$ such that whenever $n\geq n_0$ there exists a partition  $\mathcal B\sqcup \mathcal G=\alpha\vee T^{-1}\alpha\vee\cdots \vee T^{-n+1}\alpha$ such that $\mu(\bigcup \mathcal B)<\varepsilon$ and for all $G\in \mathcal G$ we have $$2^{-n (h(\alpha, T)+\varepsilon)}< \mu(G)< 2^{-n(h(\alpha, T)-\varepsilon)}$$

Comment: I didn't know that. Thanks a lot!